# How to make resposive element that displays at maximum width and height on larger screens and maintains its proportion on smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a button that has a max width of 448px and 246px on larger screens and when you shrink tje browser the button will become smaller and keep its proportion.

```
.button {
   max-height: 448px;
   max-width: 246px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

HTML is:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-8 col-sm-6 test1"> test</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-4 col-sm-6 test2"> 
              <button onclick="openCS()">Select Champion</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-12 test3"> test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried this and it does not work. When I have the browser full screen the button does not stretch to maximum dimensions.

Comment: Think you need to look into using flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, probably... maybe (we can't be accurate without You sharing any html code) is that `height:100%` will ONLY work as long as the parent has a fixed height. If You don't want/need a fixed height for the parent, all parents as far as `body` and `html` tags needs to be set at 100% height.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added the  HTML code. Setting the body at 100% didn't fix the issue. There is no way to have an element be a specific size at full screen then scale down when the screen size is smaller? On large screens the dimensions should be 246px and 448px and keep that proportion as screen size becomes smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a class selector (`.button`) in your CSS but your html `<button>` element does not have a class.

Add the `button` class to your `<button>` element.

```
<button class="button" onclick="openCS()">Select Champion</button>
```

Comment: I added button as a class it still is not scaling to the needed dimensions at full screen nor is it scaling down as needed on smaller screens. So there is no way to have a specified width and length for an element and have to scale down proportionally when reducing screen size? I haven't found a straight answer for this.

Comment: @BlackCode Please edit your question to include a Stack Snippet of a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)